# Can an MVC 4.5 template be installed into Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, entity-framework-5

All the demos and documentation I've seen online about Entity Framework 5 have been using Visual Studio 2012.  Is there any way to use Entity Framework 5 from Visual Studio 2010?  If so, do I need to use MVC4.5 or can I use an MVC4 project template still?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the EF Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/08/15/ef5-released.aspx)

> **Compatibility**
>
> This version of the NuGet package is fully compatible with Visual
>   Studio 2010 and Visual Studio 2012 and can be used for applications
>   targeting .NET 4.0 and 4.5.
>
> **Some features are only available when writing an application that
>   targets .NET 4.5**. This includes enum support, spatial data types,
>   table-valued functions and the performance improvements.

I was able to add EF5 to an MVC4 project through NuGet. You can certainly use [MVC 4](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Web+Camps+TV/Rowan-Miller-Demonstrates-Entity-Framework-5-Using-ASPNET-MVC-4), you just won't get all the new features unless you're on VS2012.

Comment: When you create a new MVC4 project template, VS automatically goes around adding references to EntityFramework 4.4.0.0.  Do you just have to manually update them?

Comment: As far as I know EF5 can only be used in 4.5 pojects and NuGet automatically references the correct library based on your project. If you navigate to \packages\EntityFramework.5.0.0\lib\net40 you'll notice the dll here is version 4.4.0. Only in \net45\ is EF 5 available. This is not immediately apparent as the NuGet Pkg Manager will say you're downloading v.5.0.0.

Comment: I really hate how MS tie EF5 into MVC4.5, and MVC4.5 into VIsual Studio 2012.  It seems totally unnecessary.